# Why does Python crash when I try to sum this numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4 (Numpy 1.9.2 and PIL.Image 1.1.7). Here's what I do:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import numpy as np

>>> img = Image.open("./tifs/18015.pdf_001.tif")
>>> arr = np.asarray(img)
>>> np.shape(arr)
(5847, 4133)

>>> arr.dtype
dtype('bool')

# all of the following four cases where I incrementally increase
# the number of rows to 700 are done instantly
>>> v = arr[1:100,1:100].sum(axis=0)
>>> v = arr[1:500,1:100].sum(axis=0)
>>> v = arr[1:600,1:100].sum(axis=0)
>>> v = arr[1:700,1:100].sum(axis=0)

# but suddenly this line makes Python crash
>>> v = arr[1:800,1:100].sum(axis=0)

fish: Job 1, “python3” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Seems to me like Python runs out of memory all of a sudden. If that is the case - how can I allocate more memory to Python? As I can see from htop my 32GB memory capacity is not even remotely depleated.

You may download the TIFF image [here](http://joyofdata.de/public/pdf2txt/18015.pdf_001.tif).

---

If I create an empty boolean array, set the pixels explicitely and then apply the summation - then it works:

```
>>> arr = np.empty((h,w), dtype=bool)
>>> arr.setflags(write=True)

>>> for r in range(h):
>>>     for c in range(w):
>>>         arr.itemset((r,c), img.getpixel((c,r)))

>>> v=arr.sum(axis=0)

>>> v.mean()
5726.8618436970719

>>> arr.shape
(5847, 4133)
```

But this "workaround" is not very satisfactory as copying every pixel takes way too long - maybe there is a faster method?

Comment: A segmentation fault *always* indicates a bug.  Even if Python were running out of memory, it would be a bug for it to crash with a segmentation fault instead of throwing an out of memory error.

Comment: It is conceivable that you are running out of stack space.  That you do not do so in the 10000 x 10000 random case could point to a difference in the algorithm used for array sections vs. the one used for whole arrays.  If a recursive algorithm were used for sections, then an array section with many discontinuous segments might recurse too deeply and exhaust the stack.  This is all speculative, of course.

Comment: The first case will also crash when not sectioned and the second case will not crash also when sectioned.

Comment: My best guess, then, is that `numpy.asarray()` is generating an array backed by part or all of the Image object (as opposed to copying all the pixel values to a separate internal representation), and numpy and PIL disagree about some aspect of the expected behavior of the Image (or perhaps PIL is just buggy).  You could probe and/or work around that by manually extracting a pixel raster from the Image object, and building your numpy array around that.

Comment: Could you tell us which versions of PIL and numpy you are using?

Comment: @all_m: (edited) Numpy 1.9.2 and PIL.Image 1.1.7

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Your hypothesis regarding conflicting internal representation does make sense. If the TIFF-`arr` was a genuine boolean numpy array then the issue should emerge also for other boolean numpy arrays - but it doesn't. Again no problem column-wise summing a random boolean 10k x 10k matrix (see end of edited question)

Comment: @Raffael, your comment about a *boolean* array got me thinking.  What if the image provided its data in packed form, i.e. 8 pixels per byte, whereas numpy assumes 1 pixel per byte?  700 * 8 = 5600, which is less than 5847, whereas 800 * 8 = 6400, which is greater than 5847.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: very well possible as the TIFF is B/W. I tried all the other TIFF encodings provided by ghostscript - to no avail. But as I show at the end of the question - the tedious pixel transferral from image to an empty numpy array works - but it takes very long

Comment: @Raffael, perhaps you can solve the problem more efficiently by converting the `Image` to a different mode.  From [the PIL docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm), it looks like you perhaps want mode "1" (mode "L" being my guess as to what you have now), so you could try `arr = np.asarray(img.convert("1"))`.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps it would help to have Ghostscript output a different format altogether, or to transform the image before reading it into your program.  For example, you could try the NetPBM "PGM" greyscale format, which Ghostscript can produce, and PIL supposedly understands.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: the idea with `img.convert("1")` makes a lot of sense - yet unfortunately doesn't affect the misresult. Regarding falling back on other formats - that's exactly what I'm going to do. But thanks for your help nonethelss - learned something!

Comment: @JohnBollinger So if I `kill -SEGV <PID_of_your_very_important_process>`, that's a bug? Well, actually, I guess that's not *truly* a segmentation fault, but to the average user, it will certainly appear to be... Also, memory bit flips (you do have ECC memory, right?) and other such things may cause true segmentation faults...

Comment: @twalberg, yes, it is a bug to execute `kill -SEGV <PID_of_your_very_important_process>`.  :^)

Comment: @twalberg, but ok, consider my earlier assertion to be qualified to "A segmentation fault almost always indicates a program bug."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your segfault using numpy v1.8.2/PIL v1.1.7 installed from the Ubuntu repositories.

- If I install numpy 1.8.2 in a virtualenv using pip (still using PIL v1.7.1 from the Ubuntu repos) then I no longer see the segfault.
- If I do the opposite (installing PIL v1.1.7 using pip, and using numpy v1.8.2 from the Ubuntu repos), I still get the segfault.

This leads me to believe that it's caused by an old bug in numpy. I haven't been able to find a good candidate in numpy's issue tracker, but I suspect that updating numpy (e.g. from the current source or via pip) would probably resolve the issue.

One workaround is to convert the image mode to `"P"` (unsigned 8-bit ints) before creating the array, then converting it back to boolean:

```
arr2 = np.asarray(img.convert("P")).astype(np.bool)
v = arr2[1:800,1:100].sum(axis=0)
```